# Finding duplicate row and flagging first row as 1 and remaining duplicate rows 0 in power query

Tags: duplicates, find, row, powerquery

I want solutions for power query.

I have one column of document numbers but it's comes as per materials sold so same document number rows increased, I need to define first row as 1 and remaining rows as 0 in Excel power query.

If anyone have solution then please share to me like m function/formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the Documentnumber column, choose **Group By**, use all the default selections

Adjust the formula in the formula bar from

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Documentnumber"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}})
```

to

```
= Table.Group(Source, {"Documentnumber"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1), type table}})
```

Expand the index column using the arrows atop the new column

Add column .. custom column ... with formula

```
= If Index = 1 then 1 else 0
```

Remove index column

File .. close and load...

Sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Documentnumber"}, {{"Count", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1), type table}}),
#"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", {"Index"}, {"Index"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Count", "Custom", each if [Index]=1 then 1 else 0),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```